# Передача переменных в подключаемый файл

Tags: файлы, php, переменные

Доброго всем времени суток господа

```
include('./block.php'); // работает
include('./block.php?alfa=1&beta=2'); // не работает
```

Собственно не могу передать get переменную в подключаемый файл. Айфреймы в моем случае не катят. В гугле пишут, что 'должно работать'. Но в реальности ошибка

```
warning: include(./block.php?alfa=1&beta=2)
failed to open stream
```

короче как бы он пытается найти не файл с переменной, а файл с таким адресом

Подскажите, как прописать GET параметры в подключаемый файл.

Comment: А что, нельзя так?

    $alfa=1;
    $beta=2;
    include('./block.php');

или так:

    $_GET["alfa"]=1;
    $_GET["beta"]=2;
    include('./block.php');

Comment: Можно, но! Есть випросы когда нужно чего то 'сделать и забыть' , на хэшкоде много таких, а есть вопросы конкретно этой командой можно сделать или нет. В моем случае для версий php 5.4.7 - оказывается есть способы (включая вышеописанный) - но нельзя (или можно) так как я указал. О чем мне кстати никто не сказал 8-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я к тому, что вашем первом посте оно подключается локально, а так нельзя, потому что оно будет искать файл с таким именем. ну да неважно уже.
`curl` конечно потянет, какая ему разница? тем более курлом можно как `GET`, так и `POST` отдавать параметры. Попробуйте использовать не `include` , а `file_get_contents`, в вашем случае это будет более оправдано, да и более правильно...

ps ни на одном своем сервере не держу пока 5.4, поэтому попробовать не могу.

pps; вы файл все же будете удаленно подключать или все же с локальной машины?

Answer (score 4):

[Третий пункт](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.include.php):

```
<?php

/* В этом примере предполагается, что www.example.com настроен на обработку .php
* файлов, но не .txt. Также, 'Works' обозначает, что переменные
* $foo и $bar доступны внутри включаемого файла. */

// Не сработает; file.txt не обрабатывается www.example.com как PHP
include 'http://www.example.com/file.txt?foo=1&bar=2';

// Не сработает; будет искаать файл 'file.php?foo=1&bar=2' в
// локальной файловой системе.
include 'file.php?foo=1&bar=2';

// Сработает.
include 'http://www.example.com/file.php?foo=1&bar=2';

$foo = 1;
$bar = 2;
include 'file.txt';  // Сработает.
include 'file.php';  // Сработает.

?>
```

Comment: попробовал как на примере

    include 'http://mysite.ru/test/test3.php?a=1';

На хостингах с php 5.2.3 - действительно работает, с 5.4.7 - не работает (массив get - пустой)

Comment: a включена опция allow_url_fopen?

Comment: когда искал решение проверял и это. этот параметр - on. ВотЪ.

Comment: ладно, а обязательно `include` нужен? вросто за все время не встречал такой необходимости подключать файлы удаленнно, может лучше посмотреть в сторону `curl`? Просто в данном случае надо перечитывать все изменения относительно 5.2, в 5.3 относительно 5.2 уже тогда много всякого было deprecated....

Comment: удаленно? да в php как бы правило хорошего тона все подключать, а не писать все в одном файле. сайт, в определенный блок инклюдится файл, т.к. не понятно какой он высоты - то iframe использовать глупо (будет или свободное место или не все влезет). Вот хочется подключить файл, и передать ему пару параметров. Такое curl разве потянет? Вместе со всеми переменными из родительного файла, и последующего приравнивания...

Если бы хоть 1 человек сказал, что у него описаное выше работает или не работает на новой версии php

Comment: c curl пока читаю хэлп, file_get_contents - подошло. спасибо огромное. Лучше так, чем никак. @thunder, что ж не в ответах? Не люблю не принятые вопросы, и влепить акцепт некуда (только верхний пост)

Comment: могу сконвертить)  
зыж сконвертил)

Answer (score 1):

Вот так же работает:

```
//index.php
<?
    include "exemple.php";
?>

//exemple.php
<?
    echo $_GET["yahoo"];
?>
```

http://...../index.php?yahoo=10

Comment: Да, но параметр берётся из запроса к index.php, а не из запроса (GET) к exemple.php, как хотел ТС.

Comment: это, как оказалось, еще неизвестно)))

Comment: Страница, ест-но на хостинге, рядом с ней вторая. вторая инклюдится в первую. При добавлении get параметров второй - ошибки. Благодаря @thunder'у вопрос решен.

Answer (score 1):

Я так понимаю, в GET-запросе к 1.php ему передаются некие параметры, на основе которых он генерирует другие параметры и передаёт их подключенному 2.php, который, в свою очередь, оперирует с полученными данными и на их основе что-то выводит. Так почему бы не поместить логику 2.php в функцию с соответствующими методами и не вызывать её из 1.php?

```
// 1.php
<?php
include "2.php";
$param1 = $_GET["param1"];
$param2 = $_GET["param2"];
someFunc($param1, $param2);
?>

// 2.php
<?php
function someFunc($param1, $param2) {
    echo $param1." ".$param2;
}
?>
```